# htaccess remove www redirect to ssl but wrong url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I created an mvc framework with php. my only working main file is index.php.

Normally I redirect from http to https. I also remove the www domain, but when I enter with www, if my URL is for example

```
domain.com/admin/products/edit/1,
```

htaccess does this.

```
domain.com/index.php/products/edit/1
```

how can i solve this
Thank you

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have your rules like this way, always keep https redirection rule at very first place only. Please clear your browser cache before testing your URLs(rest of the rules are from OP's tried rules + I have changed regex of matching hostname too here).

```
RewriteEngine ON

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)(example\.com) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```